# How to change minSDK Version in Eclipse Android project (recurring errors when saving)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on making BlueTooth Chat Android sample to communicate with another BlueTooth device.
I can Compile, build and run the modified project, but everytime I save the project, a lot of errors appear

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 1):
>   android.app.ActionBar#setSubtitle

I think I understand that I should change minSDK in the android Manifest, but when I change

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="11" />
```

It does not change anything, when I save, the same message shows up again. How can I change the minSDK of my project?

Many thanks

Comment: did you clean your project?

Comment: Actually, I have to clean my project everytime I am saving. That's the reason why this is not blocking. But I think you understand this is very annoying when you save you project often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [proper syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) is

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

You're missing the `android:` part. Make sure that your manifest is valid and that not any errors in it prevent the proper reading of the minSdkVersion.

The error tells you that you currently use API level 1, so the whole thing is not read correctly.

Comment: Works perfectly now, many thanks!
By the way, I don't know why the syntax was bad, provided it is a sample from Android Sdk...